# Finding four linearly independent vectors orthogonal to each other

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

I came up with these vectors:

u = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 0 \\1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
v = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ -1\\ 1 \\0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
w = \begin{bmatrix}2\\ -2\\ -4 \\0 \\ \end{bmatrix}

u and v are orthogonal. w is orthogonal to u and v. I have to find another matrix z that's orthogonal to u, v, and w, and I'm having a lot of trouble. Is there a better or more efficient way to do this than to simply keep guessing random vectors and adjusting them?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Gram-Schmidt process?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If you can find a fourth vector linearly independent of the three, then you can use [the Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to find one that's orthogonal to the three

Comment: Yes, I just learned it a few days ago. And thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: No need for G-S here. The dot products of $z$ with each of the other three vectors must vanish. This gives you a system of homogeneous linear equations, the solution to which is the null space of a certain $3\times4$ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In four dimensional euclidean space, the standard unit vectors $(1,0,0,0)\,,(0,1,0,0)\,,(0,0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,0,1)$ satisfy your condition.